# Limiting rows returned in a left join in MySQL issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables `trackings` and `responses`. I am running the query below to join the two tables based on the case/code_2 columns.

Because there will sometimes be multiple records in the `response` table for every record in the `trackings` table, I only wanted one row returned, not duplicates for each row in the response table as would normally happen.

I accomplished this using the query below which works great.

```
    SELECT T0.timestamp AS 'Creation Date', T0.ipaddress, T0.code_1 AS 'Alias', T0.code_2 AS 'Case ID', COUNT(T0.ipaddress) AS each_amount, T0.first, MAX(T1.res_id) AS 'responses'
    FROM `trackings` AS T0
    LEFT JOIN `responses` AS T1 
    ON T0.code_2 = T1.case

    JOIN (
        SELECT T2.case, MAX(T2.timestamp) AS max_date
        FROM `responses` AS T2
        GROUP BY T2.case
    ) x_temp_response_table

    ON x_temp_response_table.case = T1.case
    AND x_temp_response_table.max_date = T1.timestamp

    WHERE T0.timestamp >= '2014-04-20 00:00:00'
    AND T0.timestamp <= '2014-04-30 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY code_2
```

However because of the second join to limit the response rows to just one, it now doesn't return `trackings` rows when there is no corresponding record in the response table.

Basically before adding this second join, it would return all rows from the `trackings` table, and just stick a NULL in the 'responses' column if there was no corresponding row in the `responses` table <- This is probably obvious as it's what a left join does :-)

So ideally I would like the query above to still return all rows from the `trackings` table even if there is no corresponding row in the responses table.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately replacing JOIN with LEFT JOIN just brings back the duplicate rows. (Wow, ninja delete of your comment just then :-)

Comment: maybe `left join` with `distinct`?

Comment: Why not `LEFT JOIN x_temp_response_table` without ever joining T1?

Comment: LEFT JOIN  with DISTINCT doesn't work. If I remove the first LEFT JOIN, what do I join the `x_temp_response_table` with to limit the response rows to just 1?

Comment: As per standard we can't use normal join after a left join other wise it will not provide desired results so you should use left join in 2nd join also.

Comment: @ZafarMalik I then get duplicate rows for each response row. I am trying to get just one response row returned.

Comment: Changing the 2nd join to a LEFT JOIN should work

Comment: @dnoeth Sorry but it doesn't. I then get the duplicated rows back this query currently removes.

Comment: @superphonic yes you're right, it's a little bit more complex than that ;)

Comment: @dnoeth The second join (T2) joins using the first join (T1)... If I do the `x_temp_response_table`(T2) join first, there is no (T1) to join with?!? (another Ninja delete ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this with an awful subquery (not as performant, but)...

```
SELECT 
 T0.timestamp AS 'Creation Date', 
 T0.ipaddress, T0.code_1 AS 'Alias', 
 T0.code_2 AS 'Case ID', 
 COUNT(T0.ipaddress) AS each_amount, 
 T0.first,
 (SELECT r.res_id from responses r
  where r.case = T0.code_2
  order by r.timestamp desc
  LIMIT 1) as responses

FROM `trackings` AS T0
WHERE T0.timestamp >= '2014-04-20 00:00:00'
AND T0.timestamp <= '2014-04-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY code_2
```

Comment: The LEFT JOIN you have there is joining on the first LEFT JOIN (T1) which you have now removed...

Comment: @superphonic you're perfectly right. This one should do the trick, but you may wait for a better answer...

Comment: This works a treat! I am going to try @dnoeth answer as well. Any idea if this is any quicker or slower than using a Derived table?

Comment: @superphonic I doubt this is really "quick" (but the problem of quick and slow depends on other factors also).  Anyway, you may try to look at the execution plan of different (working) versions to keep the best one...

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but moving the `responses` join into a Derived Table should work:

```
SELECT T0.timestamp AS 'Creation Date', T0.ipaddress, T0.code_1 AS 'Alias', T0.code_2 AS 'Case ID', COUNT(T0.ipaddress) AS each_amount, T0.first, MAX(T1.res_id) AS 'responses'

FROM `trackings` AS T0
LEFT JOIN 
 ( 
   SELECT T1.case, T1.res_id
   FROM `responses` AS T1
   JOIN 
    (
      SELECT T2.CASE, MAX(T2.TIMESTAMP) AS max_date
      FROM `responses` AS T2
      GROUP BY T2.CASE
    ) x_temp_response_table
     ON x_temp_response_table.CASE = T1.CASE
    AND x_temp_response_table.max_date = T1.TIMESTAMP
 ) AS T1
ON T0.code_2 = T1.CASE

WHERE T0.TIMESTAMP >= '2014-04-20 00:00:00'
AND T0.timestamp <= '2014-04-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY code_2
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I get the error `Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'case'`

Comment: It's the `SELECT *`, you must replace it with column list. I'll edit my response

Comment: Yeah I just added them, now working a treat also. I am going to run some tests to see which of these answers is quicker as they both work as they should.

Comment: Efficency mainly depends on the optimizers capabilities. Otherwise they might be mainly based on the number of rows in both tables and how many rows qualify for those conditions. Btw, my query is Standard SQL while Raphaël's is MySQL proprietary :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. Unfortunately of the three answers yours is the slowest. Is probably down to bad table design/indexing on my part, but Raphaël's is the quickest here.

Comment: @dnoeth just a detail, your answer is also MySQL proprietary for the group by part. But I agree for the other part ;)

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus: I didn't notice that "I don't care which data you return" MySQL syntax, Life would be much easier if MySQL supported ROW_NUMBER :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try below query hope it will provide you desired results:

```
SELECT T0.timestamp AS 'Creation Date', T0.ipaddress, T0.code_1 AS 'Alias', T0.code_2 AS 'Case ID', COUNT(T0.ipaddress) AS each_amount, T0.first, MAX(T1.res_id) AS 'responses'
    FROM `trackings` AS T0
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT `case`,res_id FROM 
        (SELECT `case`,res_id FROM `responses` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) T2
        GROUP BY `case`
    ) T1

    ON T0.code_2 = T1.case 
    WHERE T0.timestamp >= '2014-04-20 00:00:00'
    AND T0.timestamp <= '2014-04-30 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY code_2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works perfectly but is slightly slower that Raphaël's attempt.